# The project type is not supported by this installation

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I am trying to use VS2005 Profession Edition (with C# installed) to open a Solution file that includes a WebSite that I was told was created using VS2005, when I get this error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The project file 'C:\path\SolutionFolder\tedWeb\tedWeb.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.
---------------------------
OK   Cancel   Help   
---------------------------
```

The Solution file refrerences the tedWeb WebSite that I speak of:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "tedWeb", "tedWeb\tedWeb.csproj", "{D6FA0976-F400-47A2-AE02-AD2E8BE838C3}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        SccProjectName = ""$/webDev", BAAAAAAA"
        SccAuxPath = ""
        SccLocalPath = ".."
        SccProvider = "MSSCCI:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        VWDPort = "2136"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

and there is a tedWeb.csproj file in the subfolder "tedWeb" below the solution file with a Product version of "8", which I believe is = 8. Here is a snippet of the csproj file.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.50727</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{D6FA0976-F400-47A2-AE02-AD2E8BE838C3}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>tedWeb</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>tedWeb</AssemblyName>
    <SccProjectName>"%24/tedWeb_dev", PPAAAAAA</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>..</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>
    </SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>MSSCCI:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe</SccProvider>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I have C# installed as I mentioned. I also set up the folder in IIS as an application using .NET 2.0...

When was the "Web Application" project type introduced? Is this an issue where I need to install a SP or add on to VS2005?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look here first: http://forums.asp.net/t/987224.aspx/1?Missing+ASP+Net+Web+Application+Template+VS+2005

Before that I would look at latest service packs for VS 2005 and see if there is one that cures the issue. I have not been on VS2005 in a long time, so this is a good safety check before messing up your system.

Comment: I think I already installed SP1, dunno if that is needed. I installed WebApplicationProjectSetup.msi and it worked. t!

Answer (score 4):

Open the project.csproj file with another editor, delete whatever you found between

```
<ProjectTypeGuids></ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: No major issue I am aware of that might result since Visual Studio 2005/2008 has a conflict understanding the "ProjectTypeGuids" defined in the .csproj file. Simply replacing that tag with these other GUIDs, you can reload the project and it should open as expected without any major implications.

Answer (score 2):

I cut my teeth in this recently.
VS 2005 initially didn't support web projects (only web sites).

The following two patches fixed this for me (install in this order).

1. [VS80-KB915364](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6071) "Update to Support Web Application Projects"
2. [WebApplicationProjectSetup.msi](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/0/6/906064ce-0bd1-4328-af40-49dca1aef87c/WebApplicationProjectSetup.msi) (direct link)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly the web application project type was introduced in Visual Studio 2005 SP1.  If this is a Web Application project you'll need SP1 to open it.